# Activity getting blanked out

Tags: android

Folks,

I am facing an issue which is driving me crazy. I know why this is happening but I don't know how to solve this. Please help.

### Problem

I am writing my own contact picker which will have the photo thumbnail, name and a checkbox that will enable selection. The contact picker activity starts when the user selects a checkbox on the main screen. Now I launch the contact picker activity and selects few contacts i.e. click on few checkboxes. When I rotate the screen those checkboxes are no longer checked (please note that I have already implemented the solution for adding checkboxes in custom listview as in http://androidcocktail.blogspot.it/2012/04/adding-checkboxes-to-custom-listview-in.html).

Now I guess this is the result of the contact activity oncreate getting called again. Here is the source code for Contact Activity -

```
public class ContactSelectionActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ContactAdapter contactAdapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_selection);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact);
        contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getContacts());
        listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
     }
```

So what I did was to introduce a check for savedInstance. The modified code looks like this -

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_selection);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact);
            contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getContacts());
            listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        }
     }
```

Now the Contact Activity just blanks out on rotation. Ideally I would like to keep the checkboxes checked whenever I rotate the screen.

EDIT:

I just now noticed that in both the cases I have the old activity still hanging around i.e. when I rotate I have two activities with all the check boxes cleared up in both the cases.

Here is the Contact Activity class -

```
public class ContactSelectionActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ContactAdapter contactAdapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_selection);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getContacts());
    listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.cancel) {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, null);
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private ArrayList<Contact> getContacts() {
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    return contacts;
}


}
```

And here is the adapter -

```
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

private ArrayList<Contact> contacts = null;

//Now start the holding checkbox value part
boolean[] checkBoxState;
private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView photo;
    TextView name;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
ViewHolder viewHolder;

public ContactAdapter(Context ctx, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Contact> data) {
    super(ctx, textViewResourceId, data);
    contacts = data;
    checkBoxState = new boolean[data.size()];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contacts.size();
}

@Override
public Contact getItem(int position) {
    return contacts.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_contact, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.selectContact);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    if (contacts != null) {
        Contact contact = contacts.get(index);

        if (contact.name != null)
            viewHolder.name.setText(contact.name);
        else
            viewHolder.name.setText("");

        if (contact.photoUri != null
                && !contact.photoUri.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            try {
                viewHolder.photo.setImageURI(Uri.parse(contact.photoUri));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else
            viewHolder.photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);

        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState[index]);
        viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    checkBoxState[index] = true;
                else
                    checkBoxState[index] = false;
            }
        });

    }
    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're half way there. You've checked if the savedInstanceState is null and if so, what to do about it. But after rotation, the savedInstanceState isn't null so you need an else statement and re-inflate what you need from the saved state. If the saved state bundle doesn't have what you need, then you need to ensure that the variable state you need is saved before the onCreate method is called.

Update: You dont need to store the whole list in the saved state. When you select a checkbox you must have some identifier of which contact you've picked. Store the identifiers of those selected. Re-inflate the listview (as you would if null) and then set the two contacts with the saved identifiers as checked.

Comment: exactly how to store a whole bunch of data in listview to some other variable? Means it is the whole contact list after all and user can select any.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not storing anything in `savedInstanceState`. You are directly checking whether `savedInstanceState` is `null` or not, it will be always `null` because no where in your code you are storing anything inside savedInstanceState.

Comment: Ok...so how do you store the whole custom listview in savedInstanceState?

Comment: @user2740002 Can you post `ContactAdapter` class?